# Missing frame numbers with PaloAlto theme

Tags: beamer

The following MWE does not print frame numbers with MacTeX 2017 (beamer v3.50, LuaTeX 1.0.4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  Bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer v3.50]

But it works with TeXLive 2016 (beamer v3.41, LuaTeX 0.95.0):

[image: beamer v3.41]

Using `setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]` instead of `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` does not help. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This change in behaviour was my fault - the problem had been fixed in commit [04b2516](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3) and will probably be included in beamer versions >= 3.51.

Until this version is available from CTAN, place the following files in your working folder:

- [beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty)
- [beamerouterthememiniframes.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthememiniframes.sty)
- [beamerouterthemesplit.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesplit.sty)
- [beamercolorthemedefault.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemedefault.sty)

**For now a quick workaround:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  Bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Alternative approach:**

In case you don't need the navigation symbols, you could also display the framenumber there. This has the additional advantage, that the sidebar will go all the way to the bottom of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\tiny\insertframenumber}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  Bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I go for the alternative approach since it fixes the short sidebar that necessitates another workaround.

Comment: I have a newer version (5.0.2) but it Ubuntu it still doesn't work. The "alternative approach" of putting `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\tiny\insertframenumber}` works like a charm though