# Why does Copenhagen theme not support showing frame numbers?

Tags: beamer, texlive-2018

I want to show **Frame Number/Total Frame Number** without navigation bar, just like the following picture:

[image: default theme works]

The below MWE works as expect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\begin{document}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame A}
Frame A
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame B}
Frame B
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame C}
Frame C
}

\end{document}
```

However, if I uncomment the second line `%\usetheme{Copenhagen}`, the **Frame Number/Total Frame Number** disappears as follows:

[image: Copenhagen not work]

My compiler is TexLive 2018 with xelatex.

Is there any way to show **Frame Number/Total Frame Number** with Copenhagen theme?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432056/36296

Comment: The problem has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3 and will probably be included in beamer versions >= 3.51.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired slide numbering add the following lines:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\hfill\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}}
```

to the preamble as shown in the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\hfill\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}}

\begin{document}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame A}
Frame A
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame B}
Frame B
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame C}
Frame C
}

\end{document}
```